# Unicode characters not displaying on SOME devices

Tags: android, unicode, character-encoding

I am getting a strange bug report from users, in some devices of certain brands (huawei, alcatel) the unicode char U02C4 (up arrowhead) is not displaying properly leaving a blank space while in the other 90% of devices it is displaying correctly.  I can't use an image instead because I use it inside text views and edit text as well as inside some code (the code needs to recognize the character). Is there any way to solve it for all users? Thanks

Comment: I realize this probably isn't an issue for you anymore but I just encountered a similar issue and this was the first question I encountered when looking for an answer. I figured now I had solved the problem for my self I would come back and answer this in the off chance that someone else ends up here after troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it is a character support issue. You can test android phones Unicode character support with the Google play app [Unicode Map](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.madore.android.unicodeMap).

I solved the issue by replacing my Unicode character with an image which I got from [this searchable index](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm) of Unicode Characters. As this was specifically ruled out in the question the other alternative solution is using a custom font stack. A guide for this can be found [here](https://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/).